# How to create an extension for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, plugin

I want to create an extension to Magento 2, but I cannot find any information. I need to create an extension that can be installed in Magento 2 by downloading from the store or following the link. Please share information.

Comment: try this i started Module Development from this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: You can create from here : https://www.rohanhapani.com/create-a-simple-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create a module separately from the magento 2, and then install it through a link or store